# Unresolved references after refactor of self-written module Pycharm, The code runs fine, the issue is the red squiggles and autocomplete

Tags: python, pycharm, python-module

I had a directory structure like this:

```
.
API
├───submodule1
├───submodule2
├───...
├───main.py
```

where main looks like this:

```
from API.submodule1 import X
....
def f1()...

if __name__=="__main__":
   choose what to run based on sys.argv
```

Since main isn't really part of the module, but a script using the module (and since otherwise I couldn't manage to run it from the terminal) I refactored to this:

```
API
├───API
│   ├───submodule1
│   ├───submodule2
└───main.py
```

now what happens is that inside submodule1 for example, if I write:

```
from submodule2 import X
```

then I get 'module not found error'
but if I write:

```
from API.submodule2 import X
```

then the code runs fine, but I get red squiggles and autocomplete doesn't work.
I've tried reading a lot of other discussions about unresolved references, writing modules etc, but nothing worked so far.

I think this is probably an issue with some configuration that stayed the same when I refactored, I didn't do the refactoring completely inside Pycharm. But I've tried invalidating caches.

Comment: Try `from .submodule2 import X`. Not really a fix, but bet it resolves your issues.

Comment: This works! not particularly satisfying, but for now its good enoug :) thank you!

Comment: I completely understand, I don't really have the satisfying answer, hence a comment. 

You could install your package, maybe an editable install like `pip install --editable .` or using something like poetry. It should make your original `API.submodule` work. There's some demands for project structure too, so make sure that's correct. IDK about adding directories to python import paths, but probably an avenue you could take there too.